# Бот не может обрабатывать события с пересланного из группы опроса

Tags: python, aiogram, handlers

Вот мой код:

```
import asyncio

from typing import Any, Final

from aiogram import Router
from aiogram.filters import Command
from aiogram.methods import TelegramMethod, SendPoll, SendMessage
from aiogram.types import Message, PollAnswer, Poll
from aiogram_i18n import I18nContext
from aiogram.fsm.context import FSMContext
from aiogram.fsm.state import State, StatesGroup

from bot.handlers.main.forms_main import purpose_form

from bot.models import DBUser
from bot.handlers.main.forms_main import purpose_form
from bot.services.database.main import create_pool, Repository
from bot.settings import Settings

from sqlalchemy import select

from bot.services.database.main import create_pool
from bot.settings import Settings

router: Final[Router] = Router(name=__name__)

async def forward_poll(message):
    chat_id_from = ""
    poll_message_id = 3

    forwarded_poll = await message.bot.forward_message(message.chat.id, chat_id_from, poll_message_id)
    return forwarded_poll

@router.message(Command("start"))
async def start_command(message: Message, i18n: I18nContext, user: DBUser) -> TelegramMethod[Any]:
    await select_users(user)
    forwarded_poll = await forward_poll(message)

@router.poll_answer()
async def handle_poll_answer(poll_answer: PollAnswer):
    if poll_answer.is_forwarded:
        poll_id = poll_answer.poll_id
        user_id = poll_answer.user.id
        selected_option = poll_answer.option_ids[0]
        
        print(f"Thank you for answering the forwarded poll (ID: {poll_id}). You selected option {selected_option}!")
```

Вроде при старте, пересылает опрос, но вот когда я выбираю вариант, он не ловит это событие и ничего не выводит

Но вот когда бот сам создает полл(опрос) он обрабатывает ответ и выводит вариант который указал пользователь